# Breadth-first search for shortest path code doesn't work

Tags: c++, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Why this code doesn't work? For this input:

```
5 5
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

it outputs strange number for shortest path to the given vertex but the matrix is ok (it contains the shortest paths to every cell in the matrix). But if I add `return 1;` or something else with `return` at the end of the function shortest path, then it outputs the correct solution. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int x,y,spath,val;
}v,c;

node mat[100][100];
int dy[] = {-1,1,0,0}, dx[] = {0,0,-1,1}, n, m;

void input()
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            cin >> mat[i][j].val;
            mat[i][j].spath = 0;
        }
    }
}

int shortest_path(node start, node end)
{
    queue<node> q;
    q.push(start);
    mat[start.y][start.x].val = 1;

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        v = q.front();
        q.pop();

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            c.y = v.y + dy[i];
            c.x = v.x + dx[i];

            if (c.y == end.y && c.x == end.x) {
                return mat[v.y][v.x].spath + 1;
            }
            else if (c.y >=0 && c.y < n && c.x >=0 && c.x < m && mat[c.y][c.x].val == 0)
                {
                    mat[c.y][c.x].val = 1;
                    mat[c.y][c.x].spath = mat[v.y][v.x].spath + 1;
                    q.push(c);
                }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    node start,end;
    start.x = start.y = 0;
    end.y = end.x = 4;
    input();
    cout << shortest_path(start,end) << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            cout << mat[i][j].spath;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this even a mystery? The shorter_path() function needs to return a value. If you don't return a value how could it possibly work? It's amazing this even compiled.

Comment: it should return a value with this code: `if (c.y == end.y && c.x == end.x) {
                return mat[v.y][v.x].spath + 1;
            }`

Comment: By inspection, you are reading outside the bounds of `mat`.

Comment: oh i posted the old version of my code but that's not the problem

Comment: That line will return a value, but what if that line is never reached?

Comment: I edited my post. Even if i change `return mat[v.y][v.x].spath + 1` to `return 1` it gives wrong output. Something else is not working

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes, it will be reached, i will make sure it always happens. the cell with coordinates end.x and end.y can be reached because i set them in main().

Comment: It's easy to test, put a `cout << "oops";` at the end of the `shortest_path()` function.

Comment: it's ok. Look in main() where i set the end coordinates. They will always be reachable because the whole matrix is set to 0 and that means that every cell is reachable.

Comment: your code works for me. see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8466e63aaffa096d)